# how to implement humble finance chart?

Tags: html, charts, implementation

hello friends i have being using humble finance chart , I am getting nothing in o/p.
i m using this links as below

http://www.humblesoftware.com/finance/

i have also implemented as in documentation but no results can any one help me to plot this chart i don't know how to give data as instructed in documentation.

http://www.humblesoftware.com/finance/documentation